# Creating an EC2 + EBS instance for API + Storage, how much does performance matter for serving images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently running a single EBS instance with an EBS volume attached.
The application currently hosted in the EBS today does 2 primary functions:

1. Web Application Front End
2. API / Backend Service that R/W to DB + Writes Images to EBS

I've noticed that depending on the amount of data processing, the front end usually suffers in performance.

My current EC2 instance is a Medium general purpose with 4GB of memory.
When the back end service is running it takes about 50% cpu utilization and around 300MB memory.

I am planning on separating it, so that API/BE will be hosted on its own instance with an EBS attached.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to allocate memory and performance to the front end services over the back-end services?
2. Is splitting the right way to do this?
3. Any other suggestions on how I should set this up?

Thank you all

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description suggests that the application comprises a web UI, an API, a controller that somehow interacts with a database, and an image processor. This is a very typical use of AWS and your intuition to separate these components is wise. I'd suggest the following approach:

1. Host the UI on a pair of instances behind an ELB
2. Run the API and controller code (assuming these are integrated) on another pair of instances behind a different ELB
3. Decouple the image processing layer by using an SQS queue.

Write the processing code as a worker that reads messages from the queue, processes images, and stores them in an S3 bucket. This avoids a single point of failure (the EBS volume) and enables parallel processing and will help you add more capacity in the future since multiple workers can process messages in the queue and store them in the S3 bucket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am still very new to AWS and all of its services. I was just looking at ELB and was trying to figure out best way of hosting the separate applications. 

I havent read up on SQS yet, and will look into updating the code to utilize S3 and its respective APIs next. (Thanks Ben)